# How to trigger an event depending on playback position using the Vimeo JavaScript API

Tags: javascript, api, vimeo

I have the following Vimeo embedded player code, but just a snippet of it.

What I would like to do is fade in the `#homepage-layout-container-overlay` at a certain part of the video, or halfway.

Does anyone know how this is done? I think it probably involves markers or something but I am not sure.

```
// When the player is ready, add listeners for play, pause, finish, and playProgress
player.addEvent('ready', function() {
    player.addEvent('play', onPlay);
    player.addEvent('pause', onPause);
    player.addEvent('finish', onFinish);
});

$('.introContent, iframe').click(function(){
    $('.blankOverlay').fadeIn(animSpeed);
});

$('.blankOverlay').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(animSpeed);
    player.api('pause');
});
```

```
function onPlay(id) {

}

function onPause(id) {

}

function onFinish(id) {
    jQuery('#homepage-layout-container-overlay').fadeIn(animSpeed);
}
```

Comment: I edited the title, it was very vague. Feel free to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`playProgress`](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api#events) event.

> **playProgress**
>
> Fired as the video is playing. Includes seconds, percentage played, and the total duration.
>
> ```
> {
>     "seconds":"4.308",
>     "percent":"0.012",
>     "duration":"359.000"
> }
> ```

- If you wanted to use [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) halfway through, you would check for `percent >= 0.5`, since the percentage is actually a factor.
- If you wanted to use [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) at 1 minute 15 seconds, you would check for `seconds >= 75`.

This example fades in the text `HELLO THERE` after 5%, available in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wok9rtmb/6/):

HTML:

```
<iframe id="player1" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/141178611?api=1&player_id=player1" width="300" height="240" frameborder="0"></iframe>
<div id="container">HELLO THERE</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    var container = $('#container');
    container.fadeOut(0);

    var player = $f($('#player1')[0]);

    player.addEvent('ready', function() {

        player.addEvent('playProgress', function(data,id){

            if(data.percent >= 0.05) {
                container.fadeIn(3000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [timeupdate](https://developer.vimeo.com/player/sdk/reference#timeupdate) event.

```js
var options = {
  id: 144242774
}
var Player = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-video', options);
Player.on('timeupdate', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<div id="vimeo-video"></div>
<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>
```

**Output**

```
{
    "duration": 1.01,
    "percent": 0.00,
    "seconds": 1.000
}
```